# React Error - Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, jsx

...expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Hi I'm currently trying my hand at React, I'm following a tutorial which is outdated, which is causing some problems. I'm trying to amend the errors myself as I go along, however I have stumbled whilst trying to set up Routes, and receive this error;

**Error Message**

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

The code the I suspect is causing this is on my *app-client.js* file which looks like;

**app-client.js**

```
var React = require('react'),
Router = require('react-router'),
ReactDOM = require('react-dom'),
Route = Router.Route,
DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute,
App = require('./components/App'),
Audience = require('./components/audience').default,
Speaker = require('./components/speaker'),
Board = require('./components/board'),
routes;

routes = (
    <Route handler = {App}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Audience} />
        <Route path="speaker" handler={Speaker}></Route>
        <Route path="board" handler={Board}></Route>
    </Route>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Router>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

I don't suspect it is coming from my app.js file but for the sake of finding out what is wrong I have included it;

**App.js**

```
var React = require('react'),
Router = require('react-router'),
RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler,
io = require('socket.io-client'),
Header = require('./parts/header.js'),
App;

App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            status: 'disconnected',
            title: ''
        }
    },

    componentWillMount() {
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:5432/');
        this.socket.on('connect', this.connect);
        this.socket.on('disconnect', this.disconnect);
        this.socket.on('welcome', this.welcome);
    },

    connect() {
        this.setState({ status: 'connected' });
    },

    disconnect() {
        this.setState({ status: 'disconnect'});
    },

    welcome(serverState) {
        this.setState({ title: serverState.title });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status} />
                <RouteHandler />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Can someone point me in the direction of an answer or somewhere that can provide more information about this.

Comment: Looks like you're not providing the right type to React.createElement somewhere, which usually means some component isn't getting created properly. Do you get any other info about where the error occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create a `<Router/>` with the wrong thing (the whole react-router library). Try changing

```
Router = require('react-router'),
```

to

```
Router = require('react-router').Router
```

so you can use the Router property *from* React-router, not the whole module itself.

As for the error message: React expects either a string or ReactClass (which is a function/es6 class) passed as the first argument to `React.createElement()`. JSX is just a way to turn xml-style markup into the proper set of `React.createElement()`'s for you. So, when you're trying to create `<Router/>`, React.createElement(Router) is being created and the whole react-router object gets passed in, thus the complaint :)

Comment: I tried this, with not much success. But I see the point of this and it inspired me to just write the app in ES6 instead which made this a none issue.

Comment: Cool; so my solution fixed it? The main issue is not pulling in the right module, which is possible to fix in ES6 or non ES6

Comment: Great! Just making sure :) Requiring the right module can be tricky and cause hard-to-understand errors. Hoping this will help other ppl, I've run into this sort of thing by accidentally not capitalizing etc before